# Bugzilla buglist.cgi search by change history gives wrong result

Tags: search, bugzilla

I'm trying to get a csv list of bugs that were assigned to a certain assignee (e.g. newAssignee) within a given time slot in the past (e.g. January 2015), using the following query:

http://mybugzilla/buglist.cgi?chfieldfrom=2015-01-01&chfieldto=2015-01-31&chfieldvalue=newAssignee&chfield=assigned_to&ctype=csv

The result appears to be a list where the assignee changed to the desired value at ANY time, ignoring given chfieldfrom and chfieldto. Also, bugs are listed that have no change in the history within given time at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not work for me .. however here what I would do:

**Search By People**:  flag "the Bug Assignee" and write in the account-name of "newAssignee"

**Search By Change History**:  Enter the time-frame for which you want to search. Dont select any value for the fields "where ANY of the fields:" and "changed to"

Or, if you only want to see the bugs which were newly assigned to "newAssignee" in that time-slot, select "Assigne" in "where ANY of the fields:" and write the account of "newAssignee" into the field "changed to"